# Save nested list into multiple files

Tags: python

Hi everyone I have a question on how to save the nested list onto a separate txt file?

```
nested = [['a b c d e f','1 2 3 4 5 6'],['g h i j k l','7 8 9 10 11 12'], ['m n o p q','13 14 15 16 17']]
```

A1 means the first string of alphabet
N1 means first numeric string
The name should follow the pattern like below.

`A1.txt` contains `a b c d e f` takes the `nested[0][0]`

`N1.txt` contains `1 2 3 4 5 6` takes the `nested[0][1]`

`A2.txt` contains `g h i j k l` takes the `nested[1][0]`

`N2.txt` contains `7 8 9 10 11 12` takes the `nested[1][1]`

`A3.txt` contains `m n o p q` takes the `nested[2][0]`

`N3.txt` contains `13 14 15 16 17` takes the `nested[2][1]`

Can we name the A1,txt, A2,txt, A3.txt automatically with for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for i in range(len(nested)):
    with open('A'+str(i+1)+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(nested[i][0])
    with open('N'+str(i+1)+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(nested[i][1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each sub-list will always contain two strings, the first alphabetical and the second numerical, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the file's index and unpack the lists in the following way:

```py
for i, (alpha, numeric) in enumerate(nested, start=1):
    with open(f"A{i}.txt", 'w') as alpha_file, open(f"N{i}.txt", 'w') as numeric_file:
        alpha_file.write(alpha)
        numeric_file.write(numeric)
```